# I want to get all email messages from outlook folder wise and user wise through microsoftgraphAPI

Tags: email, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I want to get all email messages from outlook folder wise and user wise through microsoftgraphapi. I want to able filter like folderwise and userwise of o365 account. I want to get all messages from outlook through microsoftgraphapi.

Comment: I understand you want to get all messages. Thats doable. Yes, Folderwise i understand, but what you meant by user wise - please explain...

Comment: my requirement is to read all mail from user mailboxes. userwise means i have one o365 tenant and in this i have 5 user I want to read all 5 user mailbox mail, and also want to access all folder of all user and its mail. main requirement is to read all mail of user of o365 account

Comment: Cool. I shared the info to use Microsoft Graph API to access your mailboxes. Test it out and let me if it works. I moved this to answer. Consider upvoting it and accept it as answer. So it will be useful to the community as well :)

Comment: HI IT IS POSSIBLE to you share all steps one by one how can I achieve this. it is possible ti achieve everything from graphapi without powershell and can we achieve this entire through powershell without graphapi help.

Comment: my requirement is to read all mail from user mailboxes. userwise means i have one o365 tenant and in this i have 5 user I want to read all 5 user mailbox mail, and also want to access all folder of all user and its mail. main requirement is to read all mail of user of o365 account

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant flow to authenticate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) and configured with application permissions. This will enable your app to access all mailboxes in a organization on Exchange Online. For example, the Mail.Read application permission allows apps to read mail in all mailboxes without a signed-in user. When you do so, then you need to work with your administrator to configure an application access policy using [New-ApplicationAccessPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access#configure-applicationaccesspolicy) PowerShell cmdlet to configure access control or limit access to specific set of mailboxes.

Answer (score -1):

my requirement is to read all mail from user mailboxes.
userwise means i have one o365 tenant and in this i have 5 user
I want to read all 5 user mailbox mail, and also want to access all folder of all user and its mail. main requirement is to read all mail of user of o365 account